# How to consume a message without forwarding to rest of pipeline

Tags: netty

I have a handler on my server that is looking for a specific instance of an incoming message and when it arrives the handler sets an internal attribute. As I have no further use for the incoming message I don't want to send it upstream to the rest of the pipeline so I simply return from the messageReceived() method.

```
@Override
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
    if (e.getMessage() instanceof StartTimerCommand) {
        trigger.getAndSet(true);
        return;
    }

    ctx.sendUpstream(e);
}
```

This seems to have the effect of blocking my pipeline as no more messages are received from the client. How do I discard unwanted messages when I have no further use for them?

Regards

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code.  Perhaps something else is wrong?

Comment: The handler in question is number 6 in a pipeline of 9 handlers. With the handler as listed above no more messages are processed after the StartTimerCommand is received. If I remove the "return" and change handlers 7,8 & 9 to handle the StartTimerCommand as well, then everything works as expected.

Comment: Are you sure the messages you received after the first `StartTimerCommand` are not `StartTimerCommand`?  It would be great if you could help us reproduce the problem by providing a small sample application and file an issue in our issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

When you override the message received method, you take the responsibility of forwarding the message in the chain. So if you do not do it explicitly, your message gets consumed.

Whenever you need to forward your message, call:

```
super.messageReceived(ctx, e)
```

Otherwise the message will not be forwarded, which is what you want.

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
@Override
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
    if (e.getMessage() instanceof StartTimerCommand) {
         trigger.getAndSet(true);
    }
    else {
        ctx.sendUpstream(e);
    }
}
```

Using "return" in void methods looks IMHO strange/confusing

Comment: From the descriptions, it sounds like the even-handling mechanism is trashed and stops processing events. The change you proposed looks functionally equivalent. Will this code change solve the poster's problem?

Comment: That answer is not useful to the question.